# Self-referential symmetric many-to-many

Tags: ruby-datamapper

I'm quite stumped trying to model self-referential, many-to-many, symmetrical entity using Datamapper:

I want to keep track of compatibility of various software releases I'm tracking:

```
class SoftwareRelease
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :software_release_type_id, Integer
    property :version, String

    belongs_to :software_release_type
    has n, :compatibilities, child_key: [ :source_id ]
    has n, :compatible_releases, self, through: :compatibilities, via: :target
end 

class SoftwareReleaseType
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :short_name, String

  has n, :software_releases
end

class Compatibility
    include DataMapper::Resource

    belongs_to :source, 'SoftwareRelease', key: true
    belongs_to :target, 'SoftwareRelease', key: true
end
```

A given software release 'a.b.c' can have a type of 'hardware platfrom foo', while a given software release 'd.e.f' can have a type of 'hardware platform bar'.

To establish compatibility between the software release in the above code, I must perform 2 adds

```
release_a_b_c.compatible_releases << release_d_e_f
release_d_e_f.compatible_releases << release_a_b_c
```

That's kinda ugly.

I'd love to be able to do just one add and have a symmetric relationship established. I can obviously wrap 2 pushes with an instance method in `SoftwareRelease`, but that feels like I'm sweeping the ugliness under a rug. Any ideas for an elegant solution?

Much obliged,

Pawel

PS

Long time ago, active-record had [acts_as_network](https://github.com/sjlombardo/acts_as_network) plugin which did something similar. Haven't been able to find anything in the DM world.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in DM or any of its plugins to do what you want, but I would like to posit that writing an instance method to create both one-way relations is in fact fairly elegant and I wouldn't consider it "sweeping the ugliness under the rug" at all.

Part of the power of implementing object relations in classes is that the programmer gets to extend those classes in meaningful ways by creating instance methods inside the class. You have a need for a symmetrical relationship between objects, so writing that simple instance method is meaningful and self-documenting. And there is no risk of side effects or inappropriate calls because it is a public method of that specific class.

I'm not really saying anything new, here, but I think your solution is perfectly acceptable. Frankly, I would rather see relatively rare use cases pushed into the programmer's domain, rather than clutter up the DataMapper code. I don't need one of those big fat Victorinox pocket knives with every conceivable tool. :)